# Foreign Key Property is not automatically updated when DetectChanges() is called

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I have a very basic example C# program (simplification for a much more complex program) which uses EF6 with DbContext and which contains two classes:

```
Teacher   1...n   Lesson
```

There is an FK constraint which sets the FK column in lesson to null when an instance of Teacher is removed.

Example program:

```
using (var context = new EFTestEntities()) {
  // An instance of Teacher (named teacher) and Lesson (named lesson) are created,
  // both are added to the context and context.SaveChanges() is called.

  // teacher is assigned to lesson and DetectChanges() is called.

  using (var context2 = new EFTestEntities()) {
    // Get teacher from the DB, delete it and save the changes.
  }

  // Because here I know that teacher could have been changed or deleted,
  // I refresh it from the database using ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins).
  // But when SaveChanges() is called,
  // an SqlException concerning FK constraint violation is thrown.
}
```

When I debug I see:

```
lesson --> teacher (Navigation Property): null (correct)
lesson --> teacher (Foreign Key Property): ID of deleted teacher (incorrect, should be null)
```

Because the foreign key property in lesson still points to the deleted teacher, the SqlException makes sense.

But why does the foreign key property still point to the deleted teacher? It should have been set to `null` when `DetectChanges()` was called.

Observations:

- Not calling `Refresh()` and setting the navigation property to null manually: The foreign key is updated as expected. So the `Refresh()` call must have something to do with this issue.
- Calling `Reload()` of `DbEntityEntry` instead of `Refresh()` of the `ObjectContext` results in the same problem.
- Refreshing not only teacher but also lesson: Makes that `DetectChanges()` updates the foreign key as expected. But this way all changes already made to lesson are lost.

Comment: If Teacher is deleted, and there is still a Lesson assigned to it..., when you try and savechanges I'm not even sure what it would be, what "state" does it say the Teacher entity is in after Refresh() and what values does it have. On another note it seems odd to be interacting on things in this way. Are you not able to use the same db context? sounds like you have disjointed code and its a problem steamed from that consumption which should be changed rather than trying to do refresh's to update stale context awareness issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When teacher is removed the FK column in lesson is set to null. I added this to my question. After Refresh() the state is Unchanged. It then has the values from the database - apart from the foreign key property. But this should get updated when DetectChanges() is called. But it is not.

Comment: No, I can't use the same context. The real program is much more complex and it is not possible.

Comment: my guess is that you need to add it again..., but this just sound like you going to have other issue further down the road.

Comment: Detaching the lesson instance, reattaching it and setting its state to Modified: Makes indeed that `DetectChanges()` updates the foreign key as expected again. But I would need to do that each time I use the `Refresh()` method.

Comment: yeah so i was correct it has become detached from the entity. I would change your design.... as again this does not sound like the best way to go.